# Choosing between Multiplicative and additive Holt Winters model

Tags: time-series, forecasting, optimization

I´m doing a prevision of the demand of a tool, I´m gonna use the Holt-Winters method but I am not sure about using the multiplicative one or the additive. I decided to isolate the seasonality by subtracting the centered moving averages to the original demand and plot it on a graphic so I could observe the change in the seasonality amplitude as the level decreases. Is that correct? My time series is a decreasing one. All the data as well as the graphic I made to highlight why I Chose the multiplicative one are down below.

[image: These are the data]

[image: This is the graphic I´m not sure about it]